# How to increment a pointer after a return statement?

Tags: java

This is my understanding of the project (horrible TA's): We're given an array in our main method that we must sort through to get a pair that adds up to 20. Once you find a pair or multiple you increment the index (that's calculating the sum) by 1.

However, 's there's a part where this is said: All you need to do is to sum the values these two pointers point to and see if they are equal to 20, if so, great! you can prepare the output of the function. If not, you inspect the sum, if the sum is greater than 20, you will decrement the second pointer and if the sum is less than 20, you increment the first pointer. So, that threw me way off.

If anyone understands what is being asked please advise me (I don't necessarily need code just kind of an explanation). Thank you!

This is my current checkSum method:

```
public static int checkSum(int[] array){
        // This function will inspect the input to find any pair of values that add up to 20
        // if it finds such a pair, it will return the *index* of the smallest value
        // if it does not find such as pair, it will return -1;
        
        int twenty = 20;
        int zero = 0;
        int checkIndex = array.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for (int k = i + 1; k < array.length; k++){
                if (array[i] + array[k] == twenty){
                    System.out.println("this print out 20");
                    System.out.println(+ array [k] + " + " + array[i]);
                    if (array [k] >= array [zero]){
                        //need to print out the index of the minimum value
                        checkIndex = zero;
                        
                        
                    }
                    checkIndex++;
                }
                }
        }// remove the following line after you are done writing the function
        //System.out.println(checkIndex);
        return checkIndex;

  }
```

this is the main method that is already provided:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1 = new int[]{5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16};
        if (checkSum(array1) != 0){
            System.err.println("TEST1 FAILED");
        }
        int[] array2 = new int[]{3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16};
        if (checkSum(array2) != 1){
            System.err.println("TEST2 FAILED");
        }
        int[] array3 = new int[]{3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15};
        if (checkSum(array3) != 2){
            System.err.println("TEST3 FAILED");
        }
        int[] array4 = new int[]{6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16};
        if (checkSum(array4) != -1){
            System.err.println("TEST4 FAILED");
        }
        System.out.println("Done!!!");
    }
```

Comment: "The array is guaranteed to be _sorted_. Use that to your advantage." is what it is saying.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the translation is as follows...

You start with two indices, 0, and the size of the array - 1.  The first and last elements in the array.  Sum these two values.  If the sum is greater than 20.  Move the second index down by 1.  If the sum is less than 20, move the first index up by one.  If the sum is 20 return the lower index.

So for the first array, you would sum 5 and 16 (array[0], array[length - 1] which is 21.  Next, sum 5 and 15 ([0], [length - 2] which is 20 so return 0, the lower of the two indices.

In the second example, 3 and 16 [0, length - 1] is 19 so increment the first index.  The next sum is then 5 and 16 [1, length - 1] which is 21 so decrement the second index. Then sum 5 and 15 [1, length - 2]. Return the lower index which is 1.

Comment: Thank you! How would I subtract one from the index? Right now I have array1[6]--; and its doing 16-1 = 15, 15-1 = 14, 14-1.., but we need array1[6.length-1], but that gives a syntax error

Comment: You might want to clarify the methodology that you are supposed to using with the TA.  Under the hood, arrays are basically pointers to memory addresses and using the subscript operator with an index is just doing some pointer arithmetic. Generally, you don’t care about that, but I would clarify to make sure you’re not supposed to be using pointer arithmetic.  In any case array[index-- is changing the element in the array.  You don’t want that, you want to adjust the index of the element you are referencing so use array[index--] or array[index++]. Similar to what you are doing in the for loops

Answer (score 1):

These arrays are already sorted. You are asked to scan the array with two pointers: one moving from the beginning, the other moving from the end. So, for example let's take one array, and name the two pointers (or indexes) `head` and `tail`:

```
array1 = {5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16}
head = 0 --> array1[0] = 5
tail = 6 --> array1[6] = 16

You add 5 + 16 = 21 > 20

So now, you are suggested to `decrement the second pointer`, hence:
head = 0 --> array1[0] = 5
tail = 6-1 = 5 --> array1[5] = 15

You add 5 + 15 = 20, done! And the smallest index is 0.
```

The other cases are just a variation of this.

Comment: Thank you! How would I subtract one from the index? Right now I have array1[6]--; and its doing 16-1 = 15, 15-1 = 14, 14-1.., but we need array1[6.length-1], but that gives a syntax error

Comment: Remember, you want to decrease the index. I would start with `tail = array1.length`. Then, I would use `array1[tail]` when doing comparisons. And so you can then simply `tail--`, to decrease.